# Class state not found

Tags: reactjs, function, console

Problem: I am trying to `console.log()` my component state, but seem to get a undefined property.

Code:

```
class App extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {switch: false};
  }

  handleClick(){
    console.log(this.state.switch)
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}> ON </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Can someone please explain to me why I am getting an error

Comment: Apologies if you found my comment rude on the other question - I just thought that being at SO for almost a year and a half and not doing any visible research or posting any effort was a bit of a time waster when there were SO many answers readily available. The top answers in my link should have helped you.

Answer (score 2):

The context of the handleClick function is not that of the class when it is called. You can prove this by running `console.log(this)` inside the function.

To fix this, you can `bind` the function:

Add this line to the end of your constructor:

`this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);`

Source:

https://codeburst.io/binding-functions-in-react-b168d2d006cb

Comment: Ohh I see, that makes sense. Thank you for that explanation.